# Парсер файлов docx для python

Tags: python, парсер, docx

Где взять парсер для обработки `docx`

Comment: Парсера готового не знаю. Но Вы можете написать сами в принципе. Ибо docx это zip архив с xml внутри. Если Вам нужен только текст из документа, то Вы его легко получите

Comment: Это хорошая идея, тогда не понадобится инсталлить новые модули

Comment: Но как это сделать? Может натолкните где можно посмотреть.

Comment: Поищите модуль для открытия архивов, он скорее всего даже уже есть в наборе модулей, а потом парсите xml. Я не пойму в чем вопрос? Если интересно возьмите любой docx и откройте его архиватором.

Comment: Все зависит от уровня программирования и возможности самому разобраться в вопросе. Сообщество и создано для того, что бы получить совет или помощь. Вы может быть тоже задаете вопросы, которые для кого-то покажутся очевидно простыми.

Comment: docx парсятся так 1.Разпаковать 2.Преобразовать xml например с помощью xslt. 3. Рендерить в нужный формат.

Answer (score 1):

Есть замечательный модуль для работы с docx: `pip install python-docx`

```
import re
from docx import Document

document = Document("Обеденное меню 777.docx")

# Регулярка для поиска последовательностей пробелов: от двух подряд и более
multi_space_pattern = re.compile(r'\s{2,}')

for table in document.tables:
    for row in table.rows:
        name, weight, price = [multi_space_pattern.sub(' ', i.text.strip()) for i in row.cells]

        if name == weight == price or (not weight or not price):
            print()
            name = name.title()
            print(name)
            continue

        print('{} {} {}'.format(name, weight, price))

    # Таблицы в меню дублируются
    break
```

Консоль:

```
Обеденное Меню

Салаты
Салат «Винегрет» 150 гр 45 руб.
Салат с сёмгой (вареная сёмга, рис отв., св. огурец, яйцо, соус «тар-тар») 150 гр 60 руб.

Супы
Солянка 250 мл 60 руб.
Суп грибной «Лесная поляна» 250 мл 55 руб.

...
```

---

Этот скрипт вместе с примером можно скачать тут: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/tree/6c64ecb4a6cea678892edd0a6db2bbc23d7e020e/read_docx

Comment: Спасибо, очень интересно, сейчас опробую и напишу.

Answer (score -1):

Прописал в консоли 'pip search docx parsing'.

Попробуйте модули `python-opc`, `python-docx`, `docx2txt`, все они ставятся через PIP.